# Login automatically to url

Tags: php

I found this script, which is right for me, but I would like to automatically login directly from url, how can I run the login directly from the address bar,

```
<?
    include("func.php");
    $pag = $_GET['pag'];
    if($_SESSION["utente"] == "") {
        if($_GET['c'] == "reg") {
            if($_POST['invia']) {
                if($_POST['cod'] == $_SESSION['cod']) {
                    if($_POST['pass1'] == $_POST['pass2']) {
                        $esito = reg($_POST['nome'], $_POST['cog'], $_POST['mail'], $_POST['nick'], $_POST['pass1']);
                        if($esito != "") {
                            $err = $esito;
                        }
                    }else{
                        $err .= "Le due password non coincidono!";
                    }
                }else{
                    $err .= "Il codice di autenticazione è errato!";
                }
                if($err == "") { 
                    header("Location: form.php?c=log&mex=Ti+sei+registrato+correttamente.<br>Esegui+ora+il+login!");
                }
            }
            $form = "<input type='text' name='nome' value='$_POST[nome]' />Nome<br />
            <input type='text' name='cog' value='$_POST[cog]' />Cognome<br />
            <input type='text' name='mail' value='$_POST[mail]' />E-Mail<br />
            <input type='text' name='nick' value='$_POST[nick]' />NickName<br />
            <input type='password' name='pass1' />Password<br />
            <input type='password' name='pass2' />Conferma password<br />
            <input type='text' name='cod' />Inserisci $_SESSION[cod]<br />
            <input type='submit' name='invia' value='Registrati!' />";
        }else{
            if($_POST['invia']) {
                $esito = login($_POST['nick'], $_POST['pass']);
                if($esito == "ok") {
                    $_SESSION["utente"] = "si";
                    if($pag) {
                        header("Location: ".$_SERVER["REMOTE_HOST"].$pag);
                    }else{
                        header("Location: form.php?mex=Ti+sei+autenticato!");
                    }
                }else{
                    $err .= "Nickname o password errati!";
                }
            }
            $form = "
                <input type='text' name='nick' />NickName<br />
                <input type='password' name='pass' />Password<br />
                <input type='submit' name='invia' value='Log-In' />";
        }
    }else{
        if($_GET['c'] == "logout") {
            $_SESSION["utente"] = "";
            header("Location:form.php?mex=Logout+eseguito!");
        }
        $ok = "<a href='form.php?c=logout'>Logout</a><br />Metti qui un elenco delle pagine private.";
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Script ProteggiPag v.1.1</h2>
        <h3><?=$_GET['mex'];?></h3>
        <?
            if($ok) {
                echo $ok;
            }else{
        ?>
        <form method='post' action='form.php?c=<?=$_GET['c'];?>&pag=<?=$pag;?>'>
            <?=$form; ?>
            <h3><?=$err;?></h3>
        </form>
        <a href="form.php?c=reg">Non hai ancora un account?</a>
        <? } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried with

http://example.com/login.php?username=myusername&password=mypassword

but I can not access

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for this syntax: `http://username:password@example.com/login.php`? If your username is an email address you should encode `@` in that address as `%40`.

Comment: There is no way to login by url because this script uses $_POST

Comment: Yes, PHPLego, you're right. In the case of the URL I gave you should use `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: sorry for my English, but I do not know if I can run or not automatic login, or if I have to change the script how can I change it